# setting default value of superglobal

Tags: php

I have been working on a Timesheet Management website. I have my home page as `index.php`

```
//index.php (only relevant portion shown)
<?php
      session_start();

    if($_SESSION['logged']=='set')
    {

       $x=$_SESSION['username'];

              echo '<div align="right">';
              echo 'Welcome ' .$x.'<br/>';
              echo'<a href="logout.php" class="links">&nbsp;<b><u>Logout</u></b></a>' ;   

    }   

    else if($_SESSION['logged']='unset')
    {
             echo'<form id="searchform" method="post" action="processing.php">
                  <div>
                  <div align="right">
                  Username&nbsp;<input type="text" name="username" id="s" size="15" value="" />
                  &nbsp;Password&nbsp;<input type="password" name="pass" id="s" size="15" value="" />
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  </div>
                  </form> ';

     }
?>
```

The problem I am facing is that during the first run of this script I get an error `Notice: Undefined index: logged in C:\wamp\www\ps\index.php` but after refreshing the page the error vanishes.

How can I correct this problem? `logged` is a variable which helps determine whether the user is logged in or not. When the user is logged in `$_SESSION['logged']` is set, otherwise unset. I want the default value of `$_SESSION['logged']` to be `unset` prior to the execution of the script. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the session is initially started, `$_SESSION` is an empty array and `$_SESSION['logged']` does not exist. And read access to uninitialized variables or array indexes throw a notice (given that the error reporting level covers notices):

```
echo $undefinedVariable;

$emptyArray = array();
echo $emptyArray['undefined index'];
```

To tackle this you should test if the variable or array index you want to read actually exists. For variables there is [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) and for array indices you can either use `isset` too or [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists).

Comment: Why don't I get an error when I refresh the page? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav: You set the session variable within the `if` condition: `if($_SESSION['logged']='unset')` (notice the assignment operator). That’s why the variable is set when refreshing.

Answer (score 2):

you can also prevent a function from throwing an error if you use the '@' symbol, e.g. @function_call();.

do you really want to do "if($_SESSION['logged']='unset')" ? if you want to make an assignment, consider taking out the "if" to make your code more legible. otherwise, you probably wanted to use the equality operator. :-)